# Answering your own meta question

Tags: support, winterbash

I saw on the Winter Bash site that I could earn a hat for posting a question (+1) on meta, and also that I could earn a hat if I answered my own question. But my question is now meta: Can I get the hat for answering my own *Meta* question?

Comment: That's a meta-meta-question. Which of course, is really only a meta-question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, then. It seems that it does not work.

Comment: I think your answer should take up a position, as in "Yes, this should be possible".

Answer (score 2):

The hat you are referring is [Constantinopolitan](http://winterba.sh/constantinopolitan), which is given in the main site for a question you posted on the meta site. That is the only hat you gain for posts on the meta site. The other hats are for posts on the main site.

> #### Constantinopolitan
>
> ask a question or provide an answer on meta with a score of 1 or more

The other hat is [Git R Done](http://winterba.sh/git-r-done).

> #### Git R Done
>
> ask and answer your own question, each with a score of 1 or more

The only exception about meta sites is *Meta Stack Overflow*, which is a site of its own, the meta site for Stack Overflow, and it doesn't have its own meta site.
On *Meta Stack Overflow*, you can get all the hats but Costantinopolitan.